# setting a badge in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hi I have this code in my background.html file, but it does not seem to be working

```
function setBadge(tab) {
  $.get("getUrlLikes.php", { url: tab.url }, function(data) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
      text: String(data)
    });
  });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(null, function(tab) {
  setBadge(tab);
});
```

Comment: "does not seem to be working" .. can you elaborate or use firebug to tell the error ?

Answer (score 1):

`onClicked` has one parameter, not two. It should be:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(setBadge);
```

Unless you mean `pageAction`?

Also you need to make sure that browser action doesn't have a popup assigned to it, otherwise `onClicked` won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Is anything actually returning from that `$.get("getUrlLikes.php"` call? You probably need to point it at `http://mydomain.com/getUrlLikes.php`.

Comment: I am including my domain in the actual code, but Its a private domain that i dont want people visiting at the moment, the problem is I have tried putting an alert in the setBadge function but the function does not seem to be firing on tab change

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is a jQuery-ism. Have you loaded jQuery?